# GLIBC 2.27 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not working with ./configure

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc

I have recently been trying to use GLIBC to create a Linux Distro I am using this guide: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source

It says to run this command:
BUILD_CC="gcc" CC="${LJOS_TARGET}-gcc" 
AR="${LJOS_TARGET}-ar" 
RANLIB="${LJOS_TARGET}-ranlib" CFLAGS="-O2" 
../glibc-2.27/configure --prefix=/usr 
--host=${LJOS_TARGET} --build=${LJOS_HOST} 
--disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-tls 
--enable-kernel=2.6.32 --with-__thread 
--with-binutils=${LJOS}/cross-tools/bin 
--with-headers=${LJOS}/usr/include 
--cache-file=config.cache

Where it says LJOS I have changed to my PATH and it says it cant compile suffixes and objects. If I could have any help it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
DolphinFlopFish

Comment: » configure --prefix=/usr « : If you ínstall to /usr/, it will destroy your OS. .... Build prerequisites, see "Linux From Scratch" https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/8.2/chapter02/hostreqs.html   ... and please run `version-check.sh`

Comment: Why are you using a tutorial from 3 years ago? All of the packages referenced are outdated/obsolete.

Comment: Yes I should probably see the version-check.sh script to see if my packages are installed

Comment: I ran the version-check.sh file and it says i've got all the packages

Comment: does anyone know a way around this, easy or hard, I don't care